# How can you loop through all of the children of a model?

Tags: django-models, django-templates, attributeerror

In Django I am trying to loop through all of the children of my Todo model. But whenever I try to run it, it gives me an AttributeError that says "Manager isn't accessible via Todo instances". My code looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Tasks</h3>
{% for t in model.objects.all %} <!-- Error -->
<p>{{t.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block options %}
<li class="bg-light py-3 w-100 px-4 rounded text-nowrap fs-4">
    <button class="text-decoration-none text-dark">Save</button>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to just put the model in the context, and then I got an error in the HTML, so I figured out that it happened when I tried to reference 'model.objects.all'.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your view you need to specify what django should pass to the template. It does not serve the entire Database; therefore queries like `in model.objects.all` inside of your templates are not allowed.

Specify the queryset inside your views.py:

```py
def todo_view(request):
    context = {}
    context['my_todos'] = my_todo_model.objects.all()
    context['most_important_todo'] = my_todo_model.objects.get(pk=1)
    # put your own logic inside the `.get` method above
    return render(request, 'my_template.html' context)
```

And then access it inside of your template like so:

```html
{% for t in my_todos %}
<p>{{ t.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{{ most_important_todo.name }}
```

Because we put a queryset inside of `my_todos` we can loop over it in the template. `most_important_todo` ist just a single object passed to the template, so we can access its properties (e.g. the name) directly.
Let me know how it goes

Comment: I still get the same error, even when I try to just get the first item. Apparently, the Django documentation says that you can only access it via model classes, not instances of it.

Comment: It is the way to go. See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#tags). Please show corresponding view, theTodo model and the full Error-Traceback. Maybe I'll find the problem there.